# read json from web into a perl variable

Tags: json, perl

I'm having some trouble with a JSON file that I'm opening from a weblink. I've adapted my code from what i used to open local kml files so the problem could be a different way perl handles json or opening online files...?

'$input{place}' comes from my html forms

```
$inputname = $input{place};
$sjson ="http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=$inputname&maxRows=1&username=rsgs";
open INPUT, "<$sjson";
  $sjsoncont.=<INPUT>;  
  close INPUT;
```

When I test by printing $sjsoncont it is empty? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot simply "open" a remote URL. Use LWP::UserAgent or LWP::Simple for this task. For example:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $sjsoncont = get "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=Berlin&maxRows=1&username=rsgs";
```

And BTW, you should always check the return value if you're using open():

```
open my $INPUT, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
```

(or `use autodie`)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `IO::All`:

```
use IO::All;
my $sjson < io->http("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=$inputname&maxRows=1&username=rsgs");
print $sjson;
```

To use this, install `IO::All::HTTP`. You can do this by running `cpan IO::All::HTTP` from the command line.

It doesn't look like you are using warnings and strict. To develop perl, you really have to do that. Every script you write should start with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Also, if you experience errors from perl that you don't understand, add this one:

```
use diagnostics;
```

Comment: `sudo curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus;sudo cpanm IO::All::HTTP`

Comment: Sure. Thats another way to install it. Just an old habit with ``cpan``.

Comment: I'm sure it's a fine way, it's just that in 14 years of kind of using perl, I generally couldn't get `cpan` to do anything right until I started using `cpanm`. Which made me sad whenever I read people saying the best thing about Perl was everything outside the core distribution..

Comment: The real problem is that many module authors believe that they can require interactive installs, but I agree that ``cpan`` hasn't got it right because it supports the modules in doing so. Pluralism is great, but having a host of different competing and incompatible package install mechanisms is just aggravating the problem. Perl needs a new package standard.

Comment: `cpan` can't control the crazy things that module authors do. I'm curious what "do anything right" means though.

Comment: @briandfoy Install a module successfully. I know plenty of people (most) haven't had a problem. Maybe it's that I was using perl on netbsd, cygwin and mac os x, but yeah, stuff didn't install. Like LWP, or DBD::MySQL... I did figure some of these (the latter) out but cpanm has made it pretty automatic. And now apologies for being totally off topic.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons a module might not install, but I can't fix such a vague problem.

Comment: Will using strict make my code stop working is I've developed it without strict?

Comment: Yes. It will stop working if you've done something that is most likely to make your code hard to debug, such as not using ``my`` to declare local variables.